# JavaScript code not working in Firefox while working very well in other broswers

Tags: javascript, html

I have programmed a script-- First I have created a `<div>....</div>` which is hidden on pageload.  Then I have created an empty textbox. Now when anyone clicks a button then the whole content of the hidden `<div>....</div>` will be loaded in the textbox. Heres the code of it:

```
<div id="hiddendiv" style="display: none;">some content</div>
<button onclick="copyfunction();">click me</button>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<script>
function copyfunction() {
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var hiddendiv = document.getElementById('hiddendiv');
textarea.value = hiddendiv.innerText;
}
</script>
```

This JavaScript is working fine on my webpage when i am viewing it  on any other browser. But when viewed in firefox, the textbox shows "undefined" as the output when the button is clicked. 
Note: All Java Add-ons are enabled and up to date. Even tried clearing all cookies but it didn't help.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no `innerText` in FF, rather it's `textContent`.

Comment: will it be supported by other top browsers like chrome or IE ??

Comment: @ Teemu got it [ http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent ]. textContent is part of the W3C spec.

Comment: all in the text: `var text = x.innerText || x.textContent` <-- cross browser

Comment: @Hasan Please follow Ispuk's link, it's very helpful for issues like this. And +1 for Mic :).

Comment: @Teemu thaks.! the link by Ispuk was very helpful. Thanks to both of you.